# Ctrl Alt T doesn't work

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I have a very strange problem on my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop with Gnome-shell 3.3.2. The default shortcut to open the terminal, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not work. If I try to change the shortcut to another shortcut (just testing) it also doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut is the shortcut there?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like that the default terminal app is not there (not listed)... make a custom shortcut for gnome-terminal and assign <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to key combination to it and see if it works. If it does I'm right and leave it just as it is. If not post a comment ;)

Comment: Oh it is there in the Dconf, using Gnome-Shell 3.3.92 on Ubuntu 12.04Beta1 (my Ubuntu 11.10 messed up so I figured I'd go to Precise). So I confirm the problem persists...

Comment: Running Ubuntu 12.04 Beta2 with gnome-shell 3.4.0 I have the same issue. Delecting the default shortcut and linking a new onw to `gnome-terminal` helped me to fix this. Should be reported on Launchpad, though.

Answer (score 2):

@vanjadjurdjevic 's post works, even in Ubuntu 12.04 (beta) with gnome-shell. You have to disable the standard keyboard shortcut, as it will not work, but if you make a new keyboard shortcut and assign it to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> It'll work!

Comment: same for 12.04 final beta

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
as the shortcut, you can redefine
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
as the shortcut in the Settings>Keyboard>Launchers settings. It seems that it's a bug and may also there is a conflit. This works for me at least.

Answer (score -1):

Check your system keyboard shortcuts:

Go to : **System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut Tab**

[image]

---

**Then** you can disable any shortcut you want :)

[image]