# Ctrl-Alt-T stopped working - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

This happens now and then and after a restart it works. No clue as to what causes this. When this happened earlier I would search for Terminal in Dash and launch. But today, even that does not work.

I have tried the solutions posted in the following posts without any luck.

- [CTRL+ALT+T not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403819/ctrlaltt-not-working)
- [Ctrl Alt T doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92747/ctrl-alt-t-doesnt-work)

I am going to restart `lightdm` first to see if that helps and if not I will restart my laptop.

I look forward to your suggestions on what else I could try for this is sure to recur.

Comment: Restarting lightdm worked.

Comment: You should add your comment as answer!

Comment: I dont believe restarting lightdm is the right solution.

Comment: experienced the same problem in 14.04 over a long period. Seems to have disappeared jan 2015 after updating.

Answer (score 20):

I have also faced that type of problem earlier and initially used to restart.

But now any type of such problem, then by using following command:

```
kill -9 -1
```

This will kill processes and return to login screen, then after login all works well & successfully.

Comment: I hate having to do this every time I log in. Is there a way to make it more permanent?

Comment: Did we have any information on the why? My 3 year old son starting mashing on my keyboard and made it so all function keys, ctrl+alt+t, super+l and many other shortcuts were no longer working. Finally when I realized the terminal wouldn't open either I searched for that alone and found this. Rebooting did nothing to help but this command did. This tells me maybe something was running in the background to prevent this stuff from working, but what?

Answer (score 6):

It's a confirmed bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1292113

I've had the same thing happening. Sometimes, after a minute or two of doing something else, a screen full of terminals I attempted to open with a series of frustrated <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>s blows up in my workspace.

If you go to launchpad, and confirm that it also affects you, it raises the priority of the bug, meaning it would be more likely to be fixed sooner.

Comment: The resolution of this bug is: fix released. I have had the same problem on 14.10 just now...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and tried to **Reset All(keyboard shortcuts)** and it worked charm.

process:

Go to Settings->Devices->Keyboard Shortcuts-> Reset All

it worked like charm

Comment: I didnt add "thank you", that was a real answer, you bot!

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer by [edit]ing it and include how you did the reset all?  (From the terminal, from a C function library, from a menu, ...)  as it is now, your answer isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

If (like me) you use gnome-session-fallback, executing:

```
pkill gnome-panel
```

should resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> stopped working - and what solved it to me was this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/67372

after doing `kill -9 -1` as suggested in Pandya's answer, I noticed an error about monitor configuration.

And so I reached the above answer that instructs to delete `/home/__username__/.config/monitors.xml`

Before this I couldn't switch language as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
as the shortcut, you can redefine 
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
 as the shortcut in the Settings > Keyboard > Launchers settings to replace the old Launch setting for `Launch terminal` (this is not to set up a new customized short key). It seems a bug and may also because there is a conflict. This works for me at least.

Answer (score -3):

Go `Settings`->`Keyboard`->`Custom Shortcuts`

[image]

Comment: This was suggested in the posts I cited in my question and tried by me already.